# 504 HTTP Error when trying to get ETH from Goerli testnet (Alchemy Goerli Faucet)

Tags: evm, testnets, smart-contract-wallets, goerli

I'm trying to get some ETH from the Alchemy GOERLY FAUCET but the client keeps sending 502 or 504 HTTP errors all day.

Do you have any alternative, please?

[image]

Comment: The following faucet just worked for me: https://goerli-faucet.pk910.de/
But It asks to do some mining.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The same problem on any of the sites for a whole day can not get GoerliETH

Now its work for me: https://bitszn.com/faucets.html
https://faucet.paradigm.xyz

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting that error, its a server side issue.

A 502 Bad Gateway Error is a general indicator that there's something wrong with a website's server communication. An overloaded server is one of the most common causes of a 502 error. This is where the server has reached its memory capacity, often activated by an unusually high number of visitors trying to access the same.

504 Gateway Timeout server error response code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not get a response in time from the upstream server that it needed in order to complete the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try again after some time. It should work.
Even at beginning I got the same status error.
After 5 minutes it worked for me.
You can also try it at: https://bitszn.com/faucets.html